# Closed form expression for $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}{n+k \choose k}{n+1 \choose k+1}X^{n-k}Y^{k}$?

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

I was trying to solve a recurrence equation and I ended up with this:
$$ A \sum \limits_{k=0}^{n} \frac{{n+k \choose k}{n \choose k}}{k+1} X^{n-k} Y^{k} $$

Now, I'm just wondering is there any way to simplify:
$$ \sum \limits_{k=0}^{n} {n+k \choose k} {n+1 \choose k+1} X^{n-k} Y^{k} $$
where $ n, X, Y \in \mathbb{N} $.

Comment: what is the recurrence?

Comment: @sku  $ a_{n} = X a_{n-1} + \frac{Y}{A} \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n-1} a_{i} a_{n-i} $ and $ a_{1} = A $

Comment: I am curious How did you get the summation in the question from this recurrence.

Comment: @sku I used SymPy to print simplified expressions for first 11 terms of this recurrence. Then I observed that that each term of recurrence is in the form of a series of X and Y, and follows a pattern very similar to Binomial Series. Then I used OEIS database to find pattern in coefficients of each term. Finally I ended up with above summation.